# Launch modelsim from Libero TCL command

Tags: tcl, modelsim

I'm working on a VHDL project in Microsemi Libero.

When I click "Simulate" in the Libero GUI, modelSim starts up and I get to see the results of my simulation.

I'd like to get the same response from a TCL command.

I can do "Execute Script...", and point Libero at a .TCL file containing the single line

```
run_tool -name {SIM_PRESYNTH}
```

...and this appears to work just fine (I get messages like "Starting Simulation...Simulation completed...The Execute Script succeeded")... *except* I don't get a modelSim window opening up to show me my simulation results.

How do I get modelSim to open at the end of a simulation using a TCL command?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, 7 months late.
In Libero ISE if I want  Synplify to popup, in the IDE, I click "Project", then "Profiles" and I set the synthesis tool not to run in batch mode.

Perhaps you can do the same for the simulator, or add a profile, which in tcl would look like this:

```
add_profile \
    -name {Synplify_b} \
    -type {synthesis} \
    -tool {Synplify} \
    -location {somewhere} \
    -args {-batch} \
    -batch 1
select_profile -name {Synplify_b}
```